# How can I get $N$ trials from binomial distribution?

Tags: binomial-distribution

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{15}{_NC_k}\times(0.1)^k\times (0.9)^{N-k} > 0.9996
$$

Is there a way to get $N$ from this? I was looking for a lots of materials but I couldn't find.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not with $0.996$ instead of $0.9996$ ?

Answer (score 1):

This inequality has no solutions. You want $N$ trials with success probability $0.1$ to yield either $0$ or more than $15$ successess with probability at most $0.0004$. A necessary condition for this is that the probability for $0$ successes is at most $0.0004$:

$$
0.9^N\le0.0004\Leftrightarrow N\ge\frac{\log0.0004}{\log0.9}\approx74.3\;.
$$

But at $N=74$, the probability for more than $15$ successes is already about $0.002$ ([Wolfram|Alpha computation)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=sum%20of%20binom%20(n,k)%20*%200.1%5Ek%20*%200.9%5E(n-k)%20for%20k%3D16..n%20where%20n%3D74), and it grows with $N$.

Comment: I cannot understand why you compute the probability for 0 successes which is at most 0.0004

Comment: @baeharam: Do you understand this sentence? "You want $N$ trials with success probability $0.1$ to yield either $0$ or more than $15$ successess with probability at most $0.0004$."

Comment: It means probability of more than 15 successes is less than or equal to 0.0004

Comment: @baeharam: What are you referring to by "it"? My sentence or your question?

Comment: My question....

Comment: @baeharam: It doesn't. Your sum starts at $k=1$. For it to mean what you wrote in the comment, it would have to start at $k=0$. If you want to ask the question with $k$ starting at $0$, please ask a new question rather than editing this one, as it's already got answers and changing it would cause confusion.

Comment: I posted again https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2908528/590853

Answer (score 0):

There is no closed-form expression for the $\text{cdf}$ of a Binomial law.

If you look at the sums of the first three terms for increasing $N$,

$$
p^2+2pq+q^2,\\
p^3+3p^2q+3pq^2=p(p^2+2pq+q^2)+pq(p+2q),\\
p^4+4p^3q+6p^2q^2=p(p^3+3p^2q+3pq^2)+p^2q(p+3q),\\
p^5+5p^4q+10p^3q^2=p(p^4+4p^3q+6p^2q^2)+p^3q(p+4q),\\
\cdots$$

a double recurrence appears (sum of the $M$ first terms as a function of the sum for $N-1$ and the sum of the $M-1$ first terms). So the amount of terms to be computed is of order $MN$.