# How can I get N trials from binomial distribution (Edited)

Tags: binomial-distribution

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{17}{_NC_k}\times 0.1^k\times 0.9^{N-k}<0.004
$$

How can I get a $N$ from above inequality?

Comment: If $N=17$ the LHS is $1$...

Comment: $N$ is not 17, I don't know $N$

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2908472) to [this related (but distinct) question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908411) is relevant.

Comment: I cannot understand what he says, what is it about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @joriki, in general for this summation a numerical approach is the way to go.

Courtesy of Wolfram Alpha, after some quick trial and error one finds that at $N = 305$ the summation is about [0.00405](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5B305,+k%5D+0.1%5Ek+0.9%5E(305+-+k),+%7Bk,+0,+17%7D%5D), and at $N = 306$ the sum is roughly [0.00385](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5B306,+k%5D+0.1%5Ek+0.9%5E(306+-+k),+%7Bk,+0,+17%7D%5D).

The minimal $N$ that satisfies your inequality is $N = 306$, which happens to be a multiple of 17.

Whether there's an analytic solution for this particular set of numbers ($17$ and $0.004 = \frac2{500}$ with $p=0.1 = \frac1{10}$) is beyond me, and I'd like to hear from anyone who has an idea.